# How to check if a matrix is empty

Tags: java, matrix

I need to check if a matrix is `null` and empty. I'm wondering how to do it.

For example, I can simply check if it's `null` applying the code below:

```py
if (matrix == null) {
    // do something
}
```

What should I do for an empty matrix?

Comment: First and foremost -- what exactly is a "matrix"? Is it a 2-dimensional array? An ArrayList of ArrayLists? A 3rd party library? What is it possibly filled with? How do you create it? What do you mean by "empty"? Do you mean, does it contain null components?

Comment: `matrix.length() == 0` , maybe?

Comment: It's a 2-D array and it's possible to fill it with all real numbers.

Comment: @Rods2292 2d array of what ? `int` ? `Integer` ? `double` ? ...

Comment: So what is empty? filled with 0's? Please help us by improving this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(matrix!=null){
   for(int i = 0 ; i < matrix.lengrh;i++){
    // check if 1D array at index i is null
    if(matrix[i]!=null){
       // check for each row element now if you want to
       // if it's an integer array, all the elements of it is 
       // initialized to 0 by default
    }
  }
}
```